# pclpy: PCL for python, installation issue with python 3.7

Tags: python, pip, package, python-3.7

I try to install the package pclpy through pypi with the following command:

```
pip install pclpy
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pclpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pclpy
```

This issue appears only with python 3.7+, 
I have no problem with environments using an older version of python.

Does anyone have an idea of how to have this package working even with python 3.7?

Comment: The precompiled wheels exist only for 64bit Python 3.6 on Windows. You can try installing directly from github repo: `pip install git+https://github.com/davidcaron/pclpy`

Comment: It doesn't work, I got this error message:
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\GMO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-3urucwoj\

@hoefling

Comment: Sure, I didn't say it'll be a trivial task - at a bare minimum, you'll need MSVC and a bunch of preinstalled stuff: PCL itself and a selection of python packages (check `requirements{,-dev}.txt` files for the listings). Once you have it all, go through the steps described [here](https://github.com/davidcaron/pclpy#to-build) until the `python setup.py install` command, then either use that command (clone the repo before) or repeat the `pip install` command. I don't use Windows and `pclpy` is not supporting Linux, so I can't guide you through the particular errors - maybe someone else can.

Comment: Did you check the official doc it says
`Only Windows and python 3.6 x64 are supported at the moment.`
So best bet for you is to use a venv and python 3.6 to work on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

pclpy for python 3.7 isn't available via pypi, but you can still install it with conda:

`conda install -c conda-forge -c davidcaron pclpy`

According to badges on the [official github page](https://github.com/davidcaron/pclpy), python 3.6-3.8 are supported. I just tested with python 3.7 (July 09, 2020).